# Does the Java/C#-like definiton of classes not work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, prototype

I realize there are several questions related to this but I couldn't quite find an answer.

So, as a big C# fanboy I'm used to declaring classes with their variables and methods. When it comes to Javascript, it offers these weird function declarations as seen on W3schools and [here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/). I kind of dislike these constructs as they don't fulfill my need for somewhat strict order and differentiation of classes and functions, plus I'd like to do it the way I'm used to for maintainability. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods), I can in fact declare classes with a constructor method and all their functions inside the declaration, however I'm confused that other sources don't even mention that option. Plus it's not quite clear to me what these specific get methods (with blanks between get and the method name) mean. Can I only use these to even interact with the object and not just define my own methods with return values and parameters?

Here is a simple attempt of how I would have declared a class, but that doesn't work.

```
class Person {
   constructor(prename,surname) {
      this.prename = prename;
      this.surname = surname;
   }

   getFullName() {
      return this.prename + " " + this.surname;
   }
}
```

Comment: The latter was intro'd in ECMAScript 6 - while the other article was written in 2006 (well before ECMA 6)

Comment: Class declaration in JavaScript is part of the newest ECMAScript, and is not available on all browsers yet. You should stick with prototype-based OO for now (IMHO)

Comment: Look up [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). You will like it if you have a C# background.

Comment: Or see http://netjs.codeplex.com

Comment: The class definitions from ECMA should be fully available for Chrome though, right?

Comment: You should get a fuller, deeper understanding of Javascript. Its not like c# or java in major ways. For instance its a weakly typed system unlike C# or java - objects don't have specific types that you declare. That's determined from the value and context in which it is used.

Comment: Check http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ for a reference on which browsers currently support what in ECMAScript 6. According to that, Chrome should support it. However the getter you've defined doesn't seem to follow the link you shared.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll try to get into it. But shouldn't my example be correct with the latest Javascript implementation (and therefore work in Chrome)?

Comment: It should be good. But be aware that class definitions in JavaScript is nothing more than syntactical sugar - it will result the same as declaring `Person` as a function that returns an object with two properties and a function. There's actually about 6 different ways to make an object in Javascript. This is merely one of them and isn't necessarily the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the article you link to is dated 2006. That's rather old, Javascript has changed since.

Specifically, you should definitely learn what new features are added in the latest official version, the Ecmascript 6. One of the new features is the syntactic sugar for class-like definitions.

http://es6-features.org

Comment: So am I interpreting this correctly that it only allows the overwrite of standard object functions (like toString()) and these getter and setter methods? So I couldn't create a method that has both parameters and a return value?

Comment: Functions don't define return values in javascript like they do in c# and java. Javascript doesn't care.  Yes parameters are defined but they're not typed. And yes, you can create a method that takes in x number of parameters and returns a string object. Lol rather old is an understatement though